# Best way to remove small nodes in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

[image]

What's the best way to automatically remove these small objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but there is no automatic way to do this as far as I know. It may be possible to script it, say for paths of a specific length, but I'm no coder.

What I usually do is switch to the Edit Paths by Nodes tool <kbd>N</kbd>, select the object, zoom in for accuracy, then and draw a selection box around the nodes to select only those you want to remove. Holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking and dragging will allow you to make a multiple selection, then hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>

An example

[image]

Comment: Thanks, hoping there was a better way.

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard tool for selecting only items smaller than a given limit. Select all big objects, move them elsewhere or lock them. Then delete everything what's left, no need to pick those small dots one by one.

Comment: Good idea, I'll give it a try.